# virtuoso open source installation problem

Tags: openssl, virtuoso

I am trying to install the [Open source virtuoso](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource). as of the docs the system must have openSSL v.0.9.8.7, after a lot of work I managed to install (this very old version of) openssl

> openssl version OpenSSL
>    0.9.7i 14 Oct 2005

I cloned the github repo of virtuoso, did ./autogen.sh and ./configure but when I try to `make` I get this

> .....
>   checking OpenSSL version... >= 0.9.8e
>   checking OpenSSL
>   version... configure: error: OpenSSL version 1.1.0 or greater is
>   currently not supported.

as I said, the installed version of openssl is 0.9.7i, so why am i getting this error?
thanks

---

**EDIT-SOLUTION**
ok. after @TallTed's answer, i did find the proper doc, which states that the openssl version is 1.0.2p. so i installed the latest openssl from my machine, and used the instructions from [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-openssl-from-source-on-linux/) to install the older version (the instructions are for v 1.0.2o, but i did go by the book and used the `p` version)
BUT this didnt work till I saw that I had to run `sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev` as well.
Maybe this would do it, but since this was on a new VM I just destroyed it and created one from scratch, and thus the successful result.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT: As [noted on the project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/796#issuecomment-865920943), Virtuoso Open Source `/develop/7` branch now supports OpenSSL versions 0.9.8e through 1.1.1, as well as LibreSSL.*

The error message you received is clearly incorrect, as the problem is that your now installed version (`0.9.7i`) is *lower* than the current minimum required version (`0.9.8e`), which itself is well lower than the current *recommended* version (`1.0.2p`).

You've misunderstood the [basic build instructions](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/blob/develop/7/README), as have others before you ([1](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/781), [2](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/765#issuecomment-415795197)), to say that the listed versions are *required* rather than the *minimum* required, which is why there's a pull request to [change them](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/pull/767/commits/7a4c5805cf1de4fcad8901a33c5f2743e4a71714).  (More detail about OpenSSL, which is a special case on that list, may be found in [the OpenSSL-specific doc](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/blob/develop/7/README.OpenSSL.md).)

Comment: Thanks. I did figured out that i missunderstood the minimum requirement on openssl, so i started using newer versions (prior to 1.1). didnt see the doc that recomended is 1.0.2. thanks for that. the thing is that now that i have installed this version, i am still getting the same error
`checking OpenSSL version... configure: error: OpenSSL version 0.9.8e or greater is required.  
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018`

Comment: @SkarosIlias - It sounds like your environment has a mixed set of components somehow, which are confusing `configure`. I'd suggest you bring this to the [github project issue space](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/), for more focused attention from Virtuoso developers, so you can more clearly share log file snippets and other command output toward solving this.

Comment: I am getting this error as well `checking OpenSSL version... configure: error: OpenSSL version 0.9.8e or greater is required.` with version 1.1.1 openssl. Is it still the case that openssl greater than 1.1.0 is *not* supported? This is based on the latest github code.

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse - The [README.OpenSSL.md](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/blob/fix/TallTed-20190723-README.OpenSSL.md/README.OpenSSL.md) remains accurate, i.e., changes for OpenSSL 1.1.x are still in process due to the substantial differences between the 1.1.x and 1.0.x APIs. (If OpenSSL were using semantic versioning, that would have been a 1.x to 2.x change, due to the API breakage.)

Comment: @SkarosIlias - Project, and answer, updated -- As [noted on the project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/796#issuecomment-865920943), Virtuoso Open Source `/develop/7` branch now supports OpenSSL versions 0.9.8e through 1.1.1, as well as LibreSSL.

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse -- @SkarosIlias - Project, and answer, updated -- As [noted on the project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/796#issuecomment-865920943), Virtuoso Open Source `/develop/7` branch now supports OpenSSL versions 0.9.8e through 1.1.1, as well as LibreSSL.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same error while installing virtuoso. These commands works for me. Check the following GitHub link for details.

https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/blob/fix/TallTed-20190723-README.OpenSSL.md/README.OpenSSL.md

To build VOS you need to run the following command which will uninstall the 1.1 SDK and replace it with the 1.0 SDK.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

Since Ubuntu installs runtime libraries for both versions of OpenSSL side-by-side, after compiling and installing VOS on your system, you can re-install the newer 1.1 SDK for compiling other programs by running this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: As [noted on the project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/796#issuecomment-865920943), Virtuoso Open Source `/develop/7` branch now supports OpenSSL versions 0.9.8e through 1.1.1, as well as LibreSSL.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an Anaconda environnement.
By default, Conda installs the OpenSSL libs version 1.1.1 in the folder /usr and breaks the Virtuoso's compilator.
You can downgrad OpenSSL in Conda with this command:

```
conda install openssl=1.0
```

After you can compile Virtuoso (and use Anaconda tools).

Comment: As [noted on the project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/796#issuecomment-865920943), Virtuoso Open Source `/develop/7` branch now supports OpenSSL versions 0.9.8e through 1.1.1, as well as LibreSSL.